# $\dim_k H^1(X, \Omega_X)$, $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ a projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Is it possible to calculate $\dim_k H^1(X, \Omega_X)$, for $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^3$ a smooth projective surface of degree $d$, without using Chern classes?

I've been trying to do this by playing around with the long exact sequences in cohomology associated to the Euler sequence and the conormal sequence
$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-d) \to i^\ast\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^3} \to \Omega_X \to 0$$
 for $i: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$.  I don't really understand Chern classes very well.  Mainly I guess I want to know whether I need them to solve this problem.

(This is homework: I was assigned to calculate the Hodge diamond of a complex projective surface, and I have the other Hodge numbers.)

Comment: Is $X$ smooth ?

Comment: Without Chern classes means without Riemann-Roch!

Comment: Does taking Euler characteristic from the conormal sequence help?

Comment: Dear Daniel, Yes, you can make this computation by playing around with exact sequences.  (You may need to appeal to Serre duality at some points to help out.)  It's been a while since I've done it, but it will work out in the end.  Regards,

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani, yes, I meant to specify that it's smooth.  Since I have the other Hodge numbers it's enough to compute the Euler characteristic from the degree, which is what I was trying to do using the conormal sequence.

Comment: @Daniel: if you're interested in how to do this with Chern classes, see Examples 1.42 to 1.48 in Eisenbud and Harris: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic720403.files/book.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know the other Hodge numbers, it suffices to compute the Euler characteristic. You can compute this using a mild generalization of Riemann-Hurwitz (which unfortunately is slightly annoying to state and which I don't know how to prove quickly) and looking at a suitable projection.

**Edit:** Some details. Recall that all projective hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of the same degree are diffeomorphic. Hence it suffices to compute the Euler characteristic of the Fermat hypersurface $X^d + Y^d + Z^d + W^d = 0$. Project onto the first two coordinates (you need to delete some points for this to be well-defined but this has a predictable effect on the Euler characteristic; here and possibly at other points in this argument I'm secretly using the fact that Euler characteristic and compactly supported Euler characteristic agree for complex varieties). This gives us a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with generic fiber curves of the form $(1 + \lambda) X^d + Z^d + W^d = 0$ minus $d$ points, whose Euler characteristic you can compute from the genus-degree formula. At $d$ points $(X : Y) = (1 : \zeta_d^i)$ there are special fibers, and as I said above, a mild generalization of Riemann-Hurwitz will help you deal with these (cut stuff up and glue it back together appropriately). The final Euler characteristic you get should be

$$\chi = d^3 - 4d^2 + 6d.$$

Comment: You're saying that I can relate the Euler characteristic of a projective hypersurface to the Euler characteristic of a hyperplane section of that hypersurface?

Comment: @Daniel: whoops, I didn't describe the map I meant to describe. I'll edit with details.

Comment: The statement I have in the back of my head as I run through this argument is the following: for nice functions $f$ on nice spaces $X$ and nice maps $\pi : X \to Y$ there is a notion of the pushforward of $f$ to $Y$ along $\pi$ which is computed by "fiberwise integration with respect to the Euler characteristic." In particular the Euler characteristic of $X$ is the pushforward of the function $1$ along the unique map $X \to \text{pt}$, and you can compute this Euler characteristic by first pushing forward $1$ to any other space $Y$, and then pushing forward again along $Y \to \text{pt}$.

Comment: (The point being that pushforward is functorial.) When $X$, say, admits a Whitney stratification and $f$ is an integer-valued constructible function then this pushforward is a decategorification of the derived pushforward of constructible sheaves, with the Euler characteristic being a decategorification of taking cohomology. But there should be an easier way to set up this theory that doesn't require going through all that machinery one category level up, possibly involving o-minimal stuff.